# increment backup in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.2

Am using postgres 8.2 & and i want take incremental backup using WAL Method, i just take full backup like `-000000010000000000000023.00000020.backup.done`

Suppose that once backup will done, after that there were some DML perform in my database and ait will write in a new file suppose -

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog/00000001000000000000003E
```

then how can restore backup after bakup file

i just want to restore changes -suppose i take full backup today 1:00 pm & there were some changes has done till 2:00 pm and after that i just want to restore that change whose has done b/w 1 to 2 pm.

Comment: 8.2 is long dead and forgotten. You should _really_ upgrade **now**

Comment: Yeah, 8.2 is laughably old. None of the tools and techniques commonly used are supported with 8.2. Upgrade. The only reason to have 8.2 still around is if it's on some server so restricted you aren't even allowed to breath near it, and you certainly wouldn't be trying to do *anything* new with it.